# IntegrityError - Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to register a new user on the site,

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,primary_key=True)#user profile
    email_id=models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
```

When I am registering the user, I am getting stuck by **Integrity Error**, please help me to resolve the problem.

```
def registration(request):
    registration_dict = {}
    if 1==1 :
    #if request.POST:
        #username=request.POST['email']
        #password=request.POST['password']
        username="admin@admin.com"
        password='123456'
        #try:
        UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(email_id=username,user__username=username,user__email=username,user__password=password)
        #except:
          #  registration_dict["status"]="0"
         #   registration_dict["message"]="Username already present"
           # return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(registration_dict),content_type="application/json")  

        registration_dict["status"]="1"
        registration_dict["message"]="Thank You for registering"
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(registration_dict),content_type="application/json") 
    else:
        registration_dict["status"]="0"
        registration_dict["message"]="Unable to process the request"
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(registration_dict),content_type="application/json")
```

**EDIT 1**
I have tried changing 
`UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(email_id=username,user__username=username,user__email=username,user__password=password,user_id=1)`
and then the error changes, to

```
'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app_info`.`appdata_userinfo`, CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_b0fd803b` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: yeah, user id is primary key. I am adding a new user,default its auto increment. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: `user_id` is the backing field for `user`, *not* the PK.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams now it is giving  'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app_info`.`appdata_userinfo`, CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_b0fd803b` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))') changed to `UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(email_id=username,user__username=username,user__email=username,user__password=password,user_id=1)`

Comment: [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited information I would say the problem is
it does not find a UserInfo that matches. It then tries to create a new UserInfo, but it has no User to assign to the User ForeignKey. I would suggest the following:

```
user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
if user is None:
     user = User(username=email, password=password, email=email)
user_info = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user, email_id=email)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original User object doesn't exist, you'll run into all kinds of problems. So, you need to break the process down into two steps.

1. Check if a `User` object exists or not, if it doesn't create it.
2. Check if a `UserInfo` object exists *for that user*, if it doesn't create it.

As there is a `ForeignKey`, you cannot do it in one step:

```
username = "admin@admin.com"
password = '123456'

obj, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
obj.set_password(password) # the proper way to set the password
obj.save()

# Now fetch or create a UserInfo object
info, created = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(email_id=username,user=obj)
```

Comment: Good point @mtnpaul - I was just answering the OP's original question. I assume he is doing something sensible with this.

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand why you need UserInfo because email is already there in User.
Issue can be corrected by splitting the fetching process

```
username = "admin@admin.com"
password = '123456'

user,status = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, password=password)
user_info = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user,email_id=username)
```